# Making 2 dimensional numpy array with two 1 dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I would like to convert 2 `numpy` arrays such as these ones:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3]]
b = [[100, 200, 300]]
```

to an array like below.

```
[[1, 100], [1, 200], [1, 300], [2, 100], [2, 200], [3, 300], [3, 100], [3, 200], [3, 300]]
```

Is this possible in NumPy?

### Thanks in advance.

(edited to clarify the point of this question.)
I'm trying to find a numpy way of solution.

Comment: Is this for school?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists)

Comment: Guys, this is for numpy arrays, not Python lists or dictionaries.

Comment: `a` and `b` are lists, as is the desired result.  The `itertools. product` works fine (though it produces a list of tuples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for `meshgrid` and `stack`:

```
a = np.array([ [1, 2, 3] ])
b = np.array([ [100, 200, 300] ])

print(np.stack(np.meshgrid(a, b)).T.reshape(-1,2))
```

The first creates a tuple of coordinate on the grid, the second stacks them. Then you just need to transpose and flatten.

Comment: This is what I've been trying to find out. Thanks for your answer.